# Changing the widget on button press Tkinter (Python)

Tags: python, tkinter

I am writing the code for a GUI that displays some text with Label and on button press, I want to change the text of my Label.
Here is my code for making a widget.

```
def makeWidget(self):
    self.widgets = []
    widget1 = Label(self, width=50, height=20)
    widget1.config(text='There is going to be smth here!')
    widget1.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH)
    self.widgets.append(widget1)
```

I am calling this function in my `__init__(self, parent=None)`. And everything is working nice. But when I am pressing the button for which I am assigning the command of `update`

```
def update(self):
    self.widgets[0].config(text='Here text should change')
```

the `Error` is appearing

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1702, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
File "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/untitled4/venv/main.py", line 17, in 
<lambda>
toolBar = [('Edit', lambda :(makeGui.update(root)), {'side': 'left'}),
File "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\untitled4\venv\Include\menu_toolbar.py", 
line 71, in update
self.widgets[0].config(text='Here text should change')
File "C:\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2098, in __getattr__
return getattr(self.tk, attr)
AttributeError: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'widgets'
```

I initial thought that the rpoblem is becouse `self.widget` is not being saved in anywhere that is why tried to save it by `self.widgets=[]`
Can someone help? How can I make changes in my widget with button press.

P.S In case the problem is not in the places I have mentioned above, here is my full code:

---

This is my `main.py`:

```
from tkinter import *
from Include.menu_toolbar import makeGui
import time
root=Tk()
menuBar = [
    ('File', 0,
     [('Open', 0, lambda: 0),
      ('Quit', 0, sys.exit)]),
    ('Edit', 0,
     [('Add', 0, lambda: 0),
      ('Remove', 0, lambda: 0)]),
    ('Help', 0,
     [('About', 0, lambda: 0),
      ('Optins', 0, lambda: 0)])
    ]
toolBar = [('Edit', lambda :(makeGui.update(root)), {'side': 'left'}),
               ('Add', lambda: 0, {'side': 'left'}),
               ('Remove', lambda: 0, {'side': 'left'})
               ]

toolbarColor = '#3C3F41'
class LocalGuiMaker(makeGui):
    def start(self):
        self.menuBar = menuBar
        self.toolBar = toolBar
        self.toolbarColor = toolbarColor
LocalGuiMaker(root).mainloop()
```

---

This is my `menu_toolbar.py`:

```
from tkinter import * 
import sys, time

class makeGui(Frame):
    menuBar = []
    toolBar = []
    toolbarColor = 'white'
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
        self.start()
        self.makeMenuBar()
        self.makeToolBar()
        self.makeWidget()
    def makeMenuBar(self):
        menubar = Menu(self.master)
        self.master.config(menu=menubar)
        for (name, u_index, items) in self.menuBar:
            pulldown = Menu(menubar)
            self.addItems(pulldown, items)
            menubar.add_cascade(label=name, underline=u_index, menu=pulldown)

    def addItems(self, menu, items):
        for item in items:
            if item == 'separator':
                menu.add_separator({})
            elif type(item[2]) != list:
                menu.add_command(label=item[0],
                             underline=item[1],
                               command=item[2])
            else:
                pullover = Menu(menu)
                addItem(pullover, item[2])
                menu.add_cascade(label=item[0],
                               underline=item[1],
                               menu=pullover)

    def makeToolBar(self):
        toolbar = Frame(self, relief=SUNKEN, bd=2, bg=self.toolbarColor)
        toolbar.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)
        for (name, command, place) in self.toolBar:
            Button(toolbar, text=name, command=command, fg='white', 
                    bg=self.toolbarColor).pack(place)
        clock = Label(toolbar, fg='white', bg=self.toolbarColor)
        clock.pack(side=RIGHT, expand=False, fill=Y)
        time1 = ''

        def tick():
            nonlocal time1
            time2 = time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
            if time2 != time1:
                time1 = time2
                clock.config(text=time1)
            clock.after(200, tick)

        tick()


    def makeWidget(self):
        self.widgets = []
        widget1 = Label(self, width=50, height=20)
        widget1.config(text='There is going to be smth here!')
        widget1.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH)
        self.widgets.append(widget1)

    def update(self):
        self.widgets[0].config(text='Here text should change')


    def start(self):
        pass
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem's in the creation of the toolbar

```
toolBar = [('Edit', lambda :(makeGui.update(root)), {'side': 'left'}),
               ('Add', lambda: 0, {'side': 'left'}),
               ('Remove', lambda: 0, {'side': 'left'})
               ]
```

And specifically `makeGui.update(root)`.

What you want the button to do is call the `update` method of the `makeGui` instance you create, but what you're doing is calling the `update` method on the `makeGui` class. The problem is you can't reference the `makeGui` instance at this point, since it doesn't exist yet.

Is there any reason for defining `menuBar`, `toolBar` and `toolbarColor` outside of the `LocalGuiMaker` class? It's already a simple wrapper around the `makeGui` class right? If you define them inside the `start` function, you *can* reference the class instance by using `self`:

```
class LocalGuiMaker(makeGui):
    def start(self):
        self.menuBar = [
                       ('File', 0,
                           [('Open', 0, lambda: 0), ('Quit', 0, sys.exit)]),
                       ('Edit', 0,
                           [('Add', 0, lambda: 0), ('Remove', 0, lambda: 0)]),
                       ('Help', 0,
                           [('About', 0, lambda: 0), ('Optins', 0, lambda: 0)])
                       ]
        self.toolBar = [
                       ('Edit', self.update, {'side': 'left'}),
                       ('Add', lambda: 0, {'side': 'left'}),
                       ('Remove', lambda: 0, {'side': 'left'})
                       ]

        self.toolbarColor = '#3C3F41'

LocalGuiMaker(root).mainloop()
```

Comment: Yeah! It really helped. Thanks